# Почему не отображается balloon yandex-map на iphone?

Tags: javascript, html, css, yandex-maps-api, iphone

Проблема вот в чем, есть сайт. На десктопах и андройдах все отлично, но при заходе с Iphone

1. Не отображается ballon у метки, при нажатии на нее.
2. Он как бы появляется снизу экрана, но почему-то невидимый, можно даже понажимать внизу карты и будет переходить по ссылкам.

https://bisurs.ru/ - сам сайт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На десктопе все хорошо

Такой вопрос, как проверить какой стиль мешает ему показаться? На Iphone есть возможность это как-то сделать. Проблема замечена только на яблочных устройствах.

Не могли бы помочь, пожалуйста, либо сказать, как посмотреть конфликтующий стиль

Comment: Уточните, ситуация ещё актуальна? Глянул на паре 11-х айфонов - панель балуна отображается. Правда такое количество меток без кластеризации - не лучший подход к визуализации данных.

Comment: Уже все решил, но спасибо за ответ. Огромное спасибо за совет, карту не я ставил, лишь устраняю ошибки